# Check if a user changed his/her nick with GuildMemberUpdated

Tags: c#, discord.net

So, in my `CommandHandler`, I created this:

```
//other CommandHandler stuff
_client.GuildMemberUpdated += UserNickChanged;
}

public async Task UserNickChanged(SocketGuildUser before, SocketGuildUser after)
{
    if (!before.Nickname.Equals(after.Nickname))
    {
        var channel = _client.GetChannel(123123123123) as SocketTextChannel;

        await channel.SendMessageAsync("User '" + before.Username + "' changed his/her nick to '" + after.Username + "' .");
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

What I want to do with this is check if a user changed his nick, check if it's the nick that was changed and then say that User "X" changed his nick to "Y". But, who would have thought, it doesn't work. It works if I remove the `if`-clause, but even then `before.Nickname` and `after.Nickname` are the same. I have the feeling that I use `SocketGuildUser before, SocketGuildUser after` incorrectly. Would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this myself and the `after` nickname seems to be the same unless you put `after.Nickname.ToString()` :

```
if (!before.Nickname.Equals(after.Nickname.ToString()))
```

No idea why this is happening, maybe a bug with the API.

Comment: Hm, thanks, but I believe I figured it out. Hence there is a possibility that `before` equals null, you first need to check that with `string nameBefore = (before.Nickname ?? before.Username);`.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't solve your problem. `Username` won't get the nickname hence making this whole operation pointless.

Comment: But it works, and does what I want, so that's fine by me. Anyway, thank you for your help.